# richcopy will not preserve security

Tags: file-transfer

I am trying to use Richcopy to transfer files from one server to another.  It seems to work well but it is not preserving ACL's.  Is there a trick to it?

Answer (score 2):

Richcopy is known for having some issues preserving ACL'S.

I recommend you look into Robocopy which is ofcourse what Richcopy is supposedly an improvement upon. The only major downside is that Robocopy does not multi-thread where as RichCopy does.

Sorry for not having a richcopy specific answer as im not sure if there is a good solution available. So hopefully this will help some.

Comment: Recent versions of Robocopy ( this is definitely the case with the versions that come with Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2) do support multi-threading - by default they use 8 threads but with the /MT switch you can specify up to 128.

Comment: oh nice, im glad to learn that.   and peter glad to here youve got it working for the time being.

Comment: The mulit-threading of RichCopy is way better with USB NAS devices... you can get a lot more speed/throughput with multi-threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it figured out.  It is working anyway.  The only user on the Source Servers ACL's that had full access was the Local Administrator group.  When richcopy transferred the files to a different server it would apply the Destination ACL's probably due to the fact that the Source Administrator Group had no rights on the Destination Server.  I applied a domain account with full access rights on the Source Files before moving them and it seems to preserve the ACL's now during the move.